# IE Debugger freezes when I "Add Watch"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, developer-tools

I am working with IE debugger for a long time.
Recently I chnaged my computer, and now when I do the following, the IE hangs.
I want to add a variable to the "Watch list".
When I do it from Right-Click on th variable, it works OK.
If I write the variable in the "Watch list" (click on the "Add Watch..." in the bottom of the list) the IE hangs.

Comment: Let me guess, IE11? Welcome to the fun. I downgraded to IE10. Despite the rendering of IE11 is imho much better than before, the developer toolbar hangs quite a lot.

Comment: I get the same problem; I wonder if I could file a bug somewhere;